# Magento 2 : How to set product stock status customer group specific?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, multi-source-inventory, cataloginventory

My requirement is wholesaler can order out of stock prdocuts.
I tried to create a plugin for the below file but it didn't work.

> \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock::addIsInStockFilterToCollection

Please help me, how can I make the stock status customer group-specific?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an extension to do this then you can consult this extension: https://amasty.com/customer-group-catalog-for-magento-2.html